# I want to download the data as a json object after sorting the table

Tags: angular12

I have an angular project in which I have successfully applied the sorting with the mat table what I want to do is that I want to download the data as a json object after sorting. Is that possible to do the same? If so how can i do the same?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this library **mat-table-exporter** it will help you in exporting the data from the material table in CSV, Excel, TXT, and JSON formats. Install it using:

```
npm i mat-table-exporter
```

Comment: Will it help me to download the data which is after sorting.

Comment: @xxoyx yes it'll help

Comment: will it support sql download also?